# O uso de pronomes retos e oblíquos com verbos causativos/de perceção

Tags: pronomes, pronomes-oblíquos, colocação-pronominal

Observe os exemplos a seguir:

**Exemplo 1:**

> a) Ouvi eles gritar.
>  
>   Ou
>  
>   b) Ouvi-os gritar.

**Exemplo 2:**

> a) Mandei ele ir embora.
>   Ou
>   b) Mandei-o ir embora.

**Exemplo 3:**

> a) Fizeram ela chorar.
>   Ou
>   b) Fizeram-na chorar.

Na letra "a" de cada exemplo usei pronomes retos(eles, ele, ela) e na "b" pronome oblíquos(os, o, na). Nesses casos qual é a forma correta ou as duas são aceitáveis. Deve-se usar pronomes retos ou oblíquos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se estivermos a falar de Português do Brasil, os exemplos em a) são os, de modo geral, mais frequentes, ao invés dos exemplos em b) que são mais facilmente encontrados no Português de Portugal.
É importante perceber que em muitos casos, o uso de ambos é correto/aceitável, consoante o contexto em que estes são aplicados, sendo que num modo mais informal se utilizam as opções em a) e para um registo mais cuidado/formal, é típico verificarem-se os exemplos dados em b).

Dados os teus exemplos, poderias ter algo como isto:

1. a) Ouvi eles a gritar / Ouvi eles gritarem / Ouvi eles gritando
   b) Ouvi-os a gritar / Ouvi-os gritar
2. a) Mandei ele ir embora
   b) Mandei-o ir embora / Mandei-o embora
3. a) Fizeram ela chorar.
   b) Fizeram-na chorar.

Confere alguma informação sobre o assunto em:
http://www.lpeu.com.br/q/eggih

Answer (score 4):

Em pt-BR há uma grande diferença entre o que se fala e o que se escreve no que concerne ao uso dos pronomes retos e oblíquos.  Falamos errado, é verdade.  Em um ambiente bem informal, uma roda de amigos, falar corretamente frases do tipo "vocês fizeram-na chorar" ou "procurei-te por toda parte", pode até ser interpretado como esnobismo.  Eu certamente não diria "eu vi ela"  provavelmente mais pelo cacófato (viela) do que pelo erro, e sempre digo "eu a vi" (não, Artefacto, não dizemos "vi-a").  Mas certamente digo: "pega ele", "fizeram ela vir até aqui", "me dá isso aí", etc, mesmo sabendo que não é o correto. Os senhores, falantes de pt-BR, conseguem imaginar alguém, sendo assaltado por um ladrão, gritar no meio da rua "Peguem-no! Peguem-no!"?  No Brasil isso certamente não aconteceria. Em momentos como esse todos gritam "Pega ele! Pega ele!

**Respondendo então à pergunta, em pt-BR e num ambiente informal, vale quase tudo. A maioria dos falantes ignora as regras e as frases do tipo (a) seriam ouvidas com frequência. Em ambientes formais, palestras, discursos, e principalmente na língua escrita, as regras gramaticais devem ser respeitadas e o uso desses mesmos exemplos é condenado.**

Regras para o uso dos pronomes pessoais retos e oblíquos [**aqui**](http://portugues.uol.com.br/gramatica/pronomes-pessoais-obliquos.html) e também [**aqui**](http://www.normaculta.com.br/pronomes-pessoais-do-caso-reto/)

Answer (score 2):

A única que não está correta é a primeira:

> Ouvi eles gritar.

O motivo é este: o pronome pessoal nominativo *eles* tem de estar a desempenhar a função de sujeito na oração com o verbo no infinitivo (*gritar*). No entanto, isto exigiria que o infinitivo estivesse flexionado. O uso do infinitivo simples com sujeito explícito não é possível em português, com excepção de alguns contextos enfáticos (*as minhas primas querem fazer **elas** o jantar*). A frase teria então de ser corrigida para *ouvi eles **gritarem***. Esta análise não é contudo aplicável ao português brasileiro informal, porque aí alguns pronomes fortes são usados tanto como sujeito, quanto como objeto.

As outras frases estão todas corretas. Além da construção com infinitivo flexionado que já referi, existem mais duas construções de infinitivo disponíveis para verbos causativos (*fazer* e *mandar*, nos teus exemplos) e de perceção (*ouvir*). Os exemplos são retirados da *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (pág. 1962).

#### Infinitivo flexionado

Este é o caso já referido.

> (157) Verbo intransitivo na oração subordinada
>   a. A professora deixou [*os alunos* saírem mais cedo].
>   b. A mãe ouviu [*as crianças* chorarem].
>
> (158) Verbo transitivo na oração subordinada
>   a. A professora mandou [*os alunos* corrigirem as redações].
>   b. Ela viu [*as crianças* atravessarem a rua].

Neste caso, o causado/percecionado antecede um verbo no infinitivo flexionado, do qual é o argumento externo. A ser substituído por um pronome, é usada a forma pronominal:

> A professora mandou [*eles* corrigirem as redações].

Se o verbo for transitivo, o pronome que substitui o objeto direto associa-se ao verbo no infinitivo:

> A professora mandou [os alunos corrigirem-*nas*].

Aqui encaixam portanto os teus exemplos frases 2a) e 3a).

#### Marcação de caso excepcional

Neste caso, o causado/percecionado continua a anteceder o verbo no infinitivo, mas este infinitivo é simples (nos exemplos, [-] é o sujeito implícito [PRO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRO_(linguistics))):

> (159) Verbo intransitivo na oração subordinada
>   a. A professora deixou *os alunos* [[-] sair mais cedo].
>   b. A mãe ouviu *as crianças* [[-] chorar].
>
> (160) Verbo transitivo na oração subordinada
>   a. A professora mandou *os alunos* [[-] corrigir as redações].
>   b. Ela viu *as crianças* [[-] atravessar a rua].

Substituindo o causado/percecionado por um pronome, este toma a forma acusativa e associa-se ao verbo causativo/de perceção:

> A professora mandou-*os* [[-] corrigir as redações].

Tal como no caso do infinitivo flexionado, o argumento interno do verbo transitivo no infinito associar-se-á a ele, se pronominalizado:

> A professora mandou os alunos [[-] corrigi-*las*].

Este é portanto o caso dos teus exemplos b), embora estes sejam ambíguos em relação à construção final, pelo facto de teres escolhido verbos intransitivos (*gritar*, *ir*, *chorar*). Se admitirmos que os pronomes fortes representam objetos e não sujeitos, como pode acontecer no português brasileiro informal, então as frases a) poderão também caber aqui (e na união de orações).

#### União de orações

Aqui o causado/percecionado ocorre em posição pós-verbal, em relação ao verbo no infinitivo, o qual não é flexionado:

> (161) Verbo intransitivo na oração subordinada
>   a. A professora deixou sair *os alunos* mais cedo.
>   b. A mãe ouviu chorar *as crianças*.
>
> (162) Verbo transitivo na oração subordinada
>   a. A professora mandou corrigir as redações *aos alunos*.
>   b. Ela viu atravessar a rua *às crianças*.

Se o verbo for intransitivo, o causado/percecionado é substituído por um pronome acusativo, o que torna a construção indistinguível da *marcação de caso excepcional*:

> A professora deixou-*os* sair mais cedo.

Por outro lado, quando o verbo é transitivo, o causado/percecionado é substituído por um pronome dativo:

> A professora mandou-*lhes* corrigir as redações.

O argumento interno também pode ser pronominalizado, caso em que toma a forma acusativa e se associa, contrariamente às duas construções anteriores, ao verbo finito:

> A professora mandou-*as* corrigir aos alunos.

E até o podem ser ambos:

> A professora mandou-*lhas* corrigir.

Esta é uma variante da união de orações por vezes chamada de *fazer-infinitivo*. Existe uma outra em que o causado/percecionado se realiza como agente da passiva, introduzido pela proposição *por*, chamada *fazer-por* mas que hoje em dia é muito pouco usada, pelo menos com o oblíquo expresso.

Aroldo Andrade no seu artigo [*Construções causativas no português antigo e clássico: O scramblinge a emergência da marcação de caso excepcional*](http://periodicos.letras.ufmg.br/index.php/relin/article/download/8421/7344) (2015), diz que a construção de *união de orações* é a construção mais antiga da língua, mas que esta se perdeu no português do Brasil:

> A inexistência de fazer-infinitivo em PB pode ser explicada em
>   termos da perda da marcação de caso dativo com a preposição a, mudança
>   que deu lugar ao desuso do paradigma de clíticos correspondente ao
>   dativo (lhe/lhes).

A *Gramática do Português* tem também esta nota de rodapé (pág. 1962):

> Quando a oração subordinada é transitiva, a construção de união de orações com verbos de perceção é considerada marginal por alguns falantes, sendo sentida como um francesismo — um juízo que por vezes também é feito sobre as frases com verbos causativos, sobretudo quando o argumento externo da oração subordinada se realiza como agente da passiva, introduzindo pela preposição *por*.

Comment: A propósito do assunto, nas frases abaixo qual ou quais das construções "dativo-enclíticas" ou "enclítico-dativas" aplicar-se-iam às frases com objeto? [/br]